# When using the method in task mode it gives a parameter error in the line image: gr.DrawImage (this.image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);

Tags: c#

When using the method in task mode it gives a parameter error in the line image: gr.DrawImage (this.image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
how can I arrange this in a way that works.Where am I going wrong? This is my abstract class that works like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Class
{
    public abstract class Img{
        
        protected Image image {get;set;}
        protected Image thumb {get;set;}
        protected int width {get;set;}
        protected int height {get;set;}
        protected string path {get;set;}
        protected string extensao {get;set;}
        protected string pathNew {get;set;}
        protected int percent {get;set;}
        protected int maxWidth {get;set;}
        protected int maxHeight {get;set;}
        public T GetPrivateProperty<T>(object obj, string propertyName)=> (T) obj.GetType()
                        .GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                        .GetValue(obj);
        

        public void SetPrivateProperty<T>(object obj, string propertyName, T value)=>
            obj.GetType()
            .GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .SetValue(obj, value);
        

       public void ResizePercent(){
            Console.WriteLine("Entrou");
            Task task = new Task(()=>this.GetImage());
            task.Start();
            task.Wait();

            this.width = Convert.ToInt32(this.width * this.percent / 100);
            this.height =Convert.ToInt32(this.height * this.percent / 100);
            this.SetBody();

        }

         public void  ResizeMax(){
            ///this.image = await Task.Run(() =>  this.GetImage());
            
            var ratioX = (double)this.maxWidth / this.image.Width;
            var ratioY = (double)this.maxHeight / this.image.Height;
            var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

            var newWidth = (int)(this.image.Width * ratio);
            var newHeight = (int)(this.image.Height * ratio);
            
            this.SetBody();
        }

        public void SetBody(){
          // Create a Bitmap object 
            Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(this.width,this.height);
            Console.WriteLine($"{this.width},{this.height},{this.image},{this.extensao},{myBitmap}");

            using(Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap)){
                gr.SmoothingMode =  SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                // Draw myBitmap to the screen.
                gr.DrawImage(this.image, 0, 0,this.width,this.height);
                
                if(this.extensao=="GIF" || this.extensao=="PNG"){
                // Get the color of a background pixel.
                    Color backColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(1, 1);

                    // Make backColor transparent for myBitmap.
                    myBitmap.MakeTransparent(backColor);
                    
                    // Draw the transparent bitmap to the screen.
                    gr.DrawImage(myBitmap,0, 0,this.width,this.height);

                }

                myBitmap.Save($"{this.pathNew}/{Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName(),this.extensao)}");
 
             }
        }

        public void GetImage(){
            Console.WriteLine("entrou GetImage");
            
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(this.path))){
                using (Image img = Image.FromStream(ms)){
                    
                    this.image=img;
                    this.extensao = this.image.RawFormat.ToString().ToUpper();
                    this.width = this.image.Width;
                    this.height = this.image.Height;
                    
                    Console.WriteLine(this.image);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is the method that generates the image but when I capture this.image in the setBody () method it gives "Parameter is not valid."

```
    public void GetImage(){
        Console.WriteLine("entrou GetImage");
        
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(this.path))){
            using (Image img = Image.FromStream(ms)){
                
                this.image=img;
                this.extensao = this.image.RawFormat.ToString().ToUpper();
                this.width = this.image.Width;
                this.height = this.image.Height;
                
                Console.WriteLine(this.image);
            }

        }

    }
```

Line error:

```
public void SetBody(){
  // Create a Bitmap object 
    Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(this.width,this.height);
    Console.WriteLine($"{this.width},{this.height},{this.image},{this.extensao},{myBitmap}");

    using(Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap)){
        gr.SmoothingMode =  SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        // Line error:
        gr.DrawImage(this.image, 0, 0,this.width,this.height);
```

Comment: `using (Image img = Image.FromStream(ms))` <--- You are disposing of the image this way. Just replace it with `this.image = Image.FromStream(ms));`.

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: I can call the Dispose method like this after giving Save () equal to: this.image.Dispose ();

Comment: You should implement the `IDisposable` interface to clean up.

Comment: public abstract class Img : IDisposable{
       private bool _disposed = false;        public void Dispose() => Dispose(true);

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing){
            if (_disposed){
                return;
            }

            if (disposing){
            // Dispose managed state (managed objects).
                this.image?.Dispose();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }

Comment: stays like this?

Comment: Yes, dispose of any managed and disposable object where you see `// TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects)`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.